# RecyclerView with ScrollView wrap_content problems

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

To begin with, I am aware of Recycler problems in old versions of libs. My current version of lib is 24.2.1.

I am trying to make a template, which contains a basic information about the item, and below this information, a list of comments. This list of comments has to wrap it's content and has to scroll with it's parent, so it should feel like a one big view.

I'm trying to do it with the following code, but RecyclerView doesnt wrap content, instead of this it has a small part on the bottom on the screen.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/news_layout_header_repost"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/cardview_inner_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/cardview_inner_margin"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/repostTextLayout"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loadComments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can you please help me?

**UPDATE**
Finally found the solution. It is better to use Relative layout. Not sure why this problem came up in LinearLayout, but the following xml structure worked:

```
<ScrollView>
   <RelativeLayout>
      <LinearLayout/>
      <RecyclerView/>
   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: did u find any answer,i am also having same problem.

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView` should never have a `wrap_content` height

Answer (score -1):

manage the height of recyclerview according to the number of child items it contain, it may solve the height issue

Comment: thanks for the reply. I also considered it as a second option. It just doesn't seem to be the most effective and clean way (though, of course, it may solve the problem)